# Seeking better dynamic programming solution to find algorithm with less complexity

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I met this question in a coding interview.

> You are in an infinite 2D grid where you can move in any of the 8 directions :
>
> (x,y) to 
>       (x+1, y), 
>       (x - 1, y), 
>       (x, y+1), 
>       (x, y-1), 
>       (x-1, y-1), 
>       (x+1,y+1), 
>       (x-1,y+1), 
>       (x+1,y-1) 
>   You are given a sequence of points you need to cover. Give the minimum number of steps in which you can achieve it. You start from the first point.
>
> Example :
>
> Input : [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
>   Output : 2
>   It takes 1 step to move from (0, 0) to (1, 1). It takes one more step to move  from (1, 1) to (1, 2).

I was able to come up with a recursive solution with memoization (DP) technic with keeping the list of visited points, but still doesn't seem perfectly optimal. I am still thinking about better solution even after the interview. Can anyone come up with better solution than I did? I need help!

```
    # @param X : list of integers
    # @param Y : list of integers
    # Points are represented by (X[i], Y[i])
    # @return an integer
        def coverPoints(self, X, Y):
            if len(X) == 1:return 0
            def odist(A, B): #to calculate shortest distance between a pair of points
                min_d =  0 if abs(A[1]-B[1]) > abs(A[0]-B[0]) else 1
                return abs(A[min_d]-B[min_d]) + (abs(A[1-min_d]-B[1-min_d])- abs(A[min_d]-B[min_d]))

            D = {}

            def rec(curL, last, dist):
                if D.get((tuple(curL), dist), False) != False:return D[(tuple(curL),dist)]
                if len(curL) == 0:return dist
                else:
                    s = sys.maxsize
                    for id, i in enumerate(curL):
                        newL = curL[:id] + curL[id+1:]
                        s = min(s, rec(newL, id, odist( (X[last], Y[last]), (X[curL[id]], Y[curL[id]]) )))
                    D[(tuple(curL),dist)] = dist + s
                    return dist + s


            s = rec([i for i in range(len(X))], 0, 0)
            return s
```

Comment: Does it have to be DP? Also, sorry for not looking over completely but what is the time complexity of your current solution (or your desired complexity)?

Comment: Could you add some more comments to your code? Trying to understand what the variables represent.

Comment: I mean, there is an obvious `n^2(logn)` solution, but your code is a bit hard to easily understand

Comment: My code literally counts all the permutations (n!) but reducing redundant computations in subs. Can you share your **n^2(logn)** logic?